# How to fix parent div unfocusing when clicking child button while parent div is focussed

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, onfocus

I have a portfolio website with some of my projects showcased on there and I'm trying to make a button in the project page that returns the user to the portfolio page when clicked. My only problem is that the parent div element loses focus when I try to click the child button instead of directing the user to the portfolio page. How do I make the parent div stop losing focus on child button click?
I've tried focussing the button element in javascript but that didn't seem to make a difference.

```js
document.getElementById('portfoliobackarrowwrapper').onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById('portfoliobackcontainer').focus();
  document.getElementById('portfoliobackarrow').focus();
};
```

```css
div.portfoliobackcontainer {
    position: fixed;
    width: 120px;
    height: 60px; 
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-left: -130px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(185, 185, 185);
    display: block;
    animation: portfoliobackanim .0001s linear;
}
  
button.portfoliobackbutton {
    background-color: orange;
    border: 1px solid rgb(214, 139, 0);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif; 
    font-size: medium;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 7.5px;
}

button.portfoliobackbutton:hover {
    border: 1px solid rgb(255, 166, 0);
    background-color: rgb(255, 184, 53);
    color:white;
    transition: all .25s linear;
    cursor: pointer;
}

div.portfoliobackarrowwrapper {
    border: 1px solid rgb(185, 185, 185);
    width: 35px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: 120px;
    margin-top: -51px;
    background-color: white;
}

div.portfoliobackarrow {
    background: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid grey;
    border-right: 3px solid grey;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    transform: rotate(315deg);
    border-radius: 2px;
    transition: .05s linear;
    margin-top: 17.5px;
    animation: portfolioarrowrotate 0.0001s linear;
}

div.portfoliobackarrowwrapper:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

div.portfoliobackarrowwrapper:hover div.portfoliobackarrow{
    border-bottom: 3px solid orange;
    border-right: 3px solid orange;
    transition: all .1s linear;
}

div.portfoliobackcontainer:focus {
    animation-fill-mode: forwards 
}

div.portfoliobackcontainer:focus div.portfoliobackarrow{
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes portfoliobackanim {
    to{
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
}

@keyframes portfolioarrowrotate {
    to {
        transform: rotate(135deg);
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
}
```

```html
 <div tabindex="-1" class="portfoliobackcontainer" id="portfoliobackcontainer">
        <button class="portfoliobackbutton" onclick="window.location='../index.html';">Portfolio</button>
        <div tabindex="-1" class="portfoliobackarrowwrapper" id="portfoliobackarrowwrapper">
        <div class="portfoliobackarrow" id="portfoliobackarrow"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: why not use just html & css. hint: use input checkbox, with [:checked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) & [adjacent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) sibling combinator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the problem you have, your code needs to be re-written, maybe not now but in the future once you get more experience.

Let me give you some tips on improving your code:

1. You can't focus 2 elements, or the previous one loses focus.
2. When you redirect to another page use anchor tag `a` and `button` for other interactions.
3. Instead of focusing the element, why not give it a class for that specific task.
4. Try to improve your classes to work without tag names like `div.class` to `.class` only. This may break your styles now but take it as advice.
5. Adopt BEM naming system for classes, it looks soo messy.

So for now, use this solution:

Replace JavaScript code with this:

```
const backArrowElement = document.getElementById('portfoliobackcontainer')
const backArrowFocusedClass = 'portfoliobackcontainerfocused'

// Toggle `focused` class.
backArrowElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (this.classList.contains(backArrowFocusedClass)) {
    this.classList.remove(backArrowFocusedClass)
  } else {
    this.classList.add(backArrowFocusedClass)
  }
})
```

And in CSS file replace class `div.portfoliobackcontainer:focus` with `div.portfoliobackcontainerfocused`

See the full code here:

```js
const backArrowElement = document.getElementById('portfoliobackcontainer')
const backArrowFocusedClass = 'portfoliobackcontainerfocused'

// Toggle `focused` class.
backArrowElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (this.classList.contains(backArrowFocusedClass)) {
    this.classList.remove(backArrowFocusedClass)
  } else {
    this.classList.add(backArrowFocusedClass)
  }
})
```

```css
div.portfoliobackcontainer {
    position: fixed;
    width: 120px;
    height: 60px; 
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-left: -130px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(185, 185, 185);
    display: block;
    animation: portfoliobackanim .0001s linear;
}

button.portfoliobackbutton {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: orange;
    border: 1px solid rgb(214, 139, 0);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif; 
    font-size: medium;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 7.5px;
}

button.portfoliobackbutton:hover {
    border: 1px solid rgb(255, 166, 0);
    background-color: rgb(255, 184, 53);
    color:white;
    transition: all .25s linear;
    cursor: pointer;
}

div.portfoliobackarrowwrapper {
    border: 1px solid rgb(185, 185, 185);
    width: 35px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: 120px;
    margin-top: -51px;
    background-color: white;
}

div.portfoliobackarrow {
    background: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid grey;
    border-right: 3px solid grey;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    transform: rotate(315deg);
    border-radius: 2px;
    transition: .05s linear;
    margin-top: 17.5px;
    animation: portfolioarrowrotate 0.0001s linear;
}

div.portfoliobackarrowwrapper:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

div.portfoliobackarrowwrapper:hover div.portfoliobackarrow{
    border-bottom: 3px solid orange;
    border-right: 3px solid orange;
    transition: all .1s linear;
}

div.portfoliobackcontainerfocused {
    animation-fill-mode: forwards 
}

div.portfoliobackcontainerfocused div.portfoliobackarrow{
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes portfoliobackanim {
    to{
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
}

@keyframes portfolioarrowrotate {
    to {
        transform: rotate(135deg);
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="-1" class="portfoliobackcontainer" id="portfoliobackcontainer">
  <button class="portfoliobackbutton" onclick="window.location='../index.html';">Portfolio</button>
  <div tabindex="-1" class="portfoliobackarrowwrapper" id="portfoliobackarrowwrapper">
    <div class="portfoliobackarrow" id="portfoliobackarrow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm thankful for all the advice coming from someone who's new in this space. I have one more question, why do u recommend to stop using div.classname and start using classes without specifying the element?

Comment: Is about Specificity in CSS. It gets harder and harder to overwrite styles after. On small projects is OK but if you inspect any real web applications no one does.